# Serialization in JSON of a class returns null value

Tags: c#, json

I am working on a universal windows 10 application. I am working with a webAPI and the I am trying to make a post call using JSON serialization of my class, 
The code is as follows:

```
public async void PostAPI()
    {
        try
        {
            var postObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(thisUser);

            string _serviceUrl = Constants.BaseUrl + "api/Account/Register";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            await client.PostAsync(new Uri(_serviceUrl), new HttpStringContent(postObject, Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8, "application/json"));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

the values for thisUser are being taken from textbox's in the UI something like this:

```
        RegisterModel thisUser = new RegisterModel();
thisUser.UserDetails = new UserDetails();
        thisUser.Email = UserInputemail.Text;
        thisUser.Password = "addsFABBS!2";
        thisUser.ConfirmPassword = "addsFABBS!2";
        thisUser.UserDetails.FullName = UserInputName.Text;
        thisUser.UserDetails.Username = UserInputUserName.Text;
        thisUser.UserDetails.FullName = UserInputName.Text;
        thisUser.UserDetails.ICEFullName = ICEName.Text;
        thisUser.UserDetails.ICEMobileNumber = int.Parse(ICEPhoneNo.Text);
        thisUser.UserDetails.DoctorFullName = DocName.Text;
        thisUser.UserDetails.DoctorMobileNumber = int.Parse(DocPhoneNo.Text);
```

The postObject remains null. it has the value {} where as in the thisUser the values are present.

the thisUser is an instance of the RegisterModel class which has the following properties:

```
  using System.Runtime.Serialization;
  namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
  {
    [DataContract]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
    }

}
```

and the user details class is as follows:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public string FullName { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string ICEFullName { get; set; }

        public int ICEMobileNumber { get; set; }

        public string DoctorFullName { get; set; }

        public int DoctorMobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to indicate the properies on this class to be data members, like so:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
  {
    [DataContract]
    public class RegisterModel
    {
        [DataMember]      
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]      
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public UserDetails UserDetails { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Same goes for the UserDetails class:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace APIValueSetterTest.Model
{
    [DataContract]
    public class UserDetails
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string ICEFullName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int ICEMobileNumber { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DoctorFullName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int DoctorMobileNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Properties not decorated with the `DataMember` attribute will result in them being ignored by the serializer.